# Open video in vlc on particular monitors

Tags: python, video, vlc, libvlc, multiple-monitors

I'n new to this topic so sorry for such a general question. 
So I have multiple monitors `m_1`, `m_2`,..., `m_n` and multiple video files `v_1`, `v_2`,..., `v_n`i want to simultaniously  open in fullscreen `v_1` on `m_1`, `v_2` on `m_2` and so on.

I was able to launch multiple videos at once in different windows but I have no idea on how to place the videos on particular monitors in fullscreen.

I'm thinking about `python-vlc` but if there's a better way please let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

```
--directx-device={,display,\\.\DISPLAY1} 
                                 Name of desired display device
          In a multiple monitor configuration, you can specify the Windows
          device name of the display that you want the video window to open on.
          For example, "\\.\DISPLAY1" or "\\.\DISPLAY2".
```

Once you figure out the proper arguments with the vlc CLI app, you should be able to feed them to libvlc through the python wrapper with `vlc.Instance('--directx-device=xxxx')`.